# Issue with codeigniter and Apache server

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I ran into a strange problem for last 4 hours. Please anyone share your experience regarding the following issue. Thanks for your time.

I have uploaded codeigniter in two different server. The urls are as followes - You can check the following urls -

```
http://www.clearindia.com/ztest/ci/index.php?welcome/index/Donec%20non%20ipsum%20eu%20sapien%20varius%20auctor%20id%20eu%20masse


http://clearbharat.com/ci/index.php?welcome/index/Donec%20non%20ipsum%20eu%20sapien%20varius%20auctor%20id%20eu%20masse
```

here the first url gives error, I tried to find where the error originates. I found that, if the text after index.php? exceeds 64 characters then I get error from system\core\CodeIgniter.php

call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));

This code does not work properly. I couldn't find the reason.

Comment: what does `$this->input->get()` output in `welcome`'s `index` function? and what error do you get? have you checked your web server's error log?

Comment: It ends up with the error -  'The connection was reset' and it get encountered in the call_user_func_array function.

Comment: Did u check your web server's error logs?